# Economic output plunged at a record-shattering 31% annual rate in 2020′s April-June quarter

Tags: prepositions

This is a sentence from [an AP News article](https://apnews.com/article/coronavirus-pandemic-business-health-prices-inflation-bd71ae9e491907a51956c1d4eb07fb90).

> Economic output **plunged at** a record-shattering 31% annual rate in
> 2020′s April-June quarter.

I suggest 'plunged to' instead of 'plunged at'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: It's such a terrible sentence that it's unclear to me how the parts relate. It's possible that "at a record-shattering annual rate" modifies "plunge" by explaining *how* it plunged, which would be acceptable grammar, but I'm not confident that's the intention.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct as written at least from the intent side; he's saying it went down *by* 31%, not *to* 31%. But that said, I'm not sure it's actually grammatical to phrase it this way.

This is a convoluted sentence at the least, which (in the context) makes me a bit suspicious of the author's intent, as does referring to an *annual* rate over a three-month period. Presumably the actual drop was 7.75% over one quarter, which would be a 31% drop *if it continued for the whole year*, which it didn't.

There are other phrasings that could be more clear, but I suspect the author didn't *want* you to understand the sentence easily; they wanted you to be shocked by the huge percentage.

Comment: Thank you very much.